# Pyautogui - locateAllOnScreen is returning locations twice or more and some not at all

Tags: python, pyautogui

So I have a short python program that is trying to locate all `1's` on the screen and prints out the amount and location of the found numbers:

```
    Ones_list = list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('path_to_png', confidence=0.90))

    if(len(Ones_list) != 0):
        print(str(len(Ones_list) + " Ones found:")
        print(*Ones_list, sep = ", ")
```

But my problem now is that pyautogui is locating some `1's` twice or even more often and some are not listed.

Example:

[image: Example:]

This is returning:

```
16 Ones found:
Box(left=74, top=459, width=28, height=23), Box(left=75, top=459, width=28, height=23), 
Box(left=595, top=460, width=28, height=23), Box(left=596, top=460, width=28, height=23), 
Box(left=1638, top=461, width=28, height=23), Box(left=1638, top=462, width=28, height=23), 
Box(left=208, top=486, width=28, height=23), Box(left=1786, top=488, width=28, height=23), 
Box(left=1787, top=488, width=28, height=23), Box(left=482, top=540, width=28, height=23), 
Box(left=481, top=541, width=28, height=23), Box(left=482, top=541, width=28, height=23), 
Box(left=220, top=597, width=28, height=23), Box(left=221, top=597, width=28, height=23), 
Box(left=803, top=718, width=28, height=23), Box(left=803, top=719, width=28, height=23)
```

But there are not 16 `1's` and looking at the coordinates of the found images I am pretty sure that not all `1's` were found just some counted more often!

How can I make sure that I locate all `1's` only once?

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with the confidence. I had mine on 0.75 but after increasing it to 0.8 or 0.9 it started working correctly.

My problem was also similar to yours, but instead locateAllOnScreen returned 4 locations for each.